# How to acces all UI elements from CarPlay with Xcode UI Recording?

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest, carplay

Why can the UI recording from Xcode accces elements like the status bar from CarPlay but not the other elements like the buttons on the map or buttons in an navigation alert?

Answer (score 1):

XCTest built-in recorder is not designed to record interactions with CarPlay display properly.

You should probably inspect elements with an Accessibility Inspector or `app.debugDescription`